# Refresh browser on click of back button JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an application which has a requirement of refreshing the browser whenever we click back button to try to go back to some other page.

How can i do that ? Is there any way to catch the back button event ?

Thanx in advance..

Comment: what you mean by refreshing the browser.? You want to stop browser from taking the old page from cache?

Comment: I simply wants to reload the current page in which i am right now.

Comment: you cannot control browser back button.

Comment: You can, to an extent. Whether it's a good idea or not is the question. https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: Ok. Then how gmail and facebook is doing the same when you log in and press back button.?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement the HTML5 [`History` interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#the-history-interface), you can react to [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) and then just [`reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the popstate event:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    window.location.reload();
};
```